# Is it possible to "dissolve" a driver and commit its effects on an animated armature?

Tags: animation, export, drivers, unreal-engine, .fbx

My ultimate goal is to export an animation from Blender to Unreal. This is generally done by filmbox (FBX) files. However, my animation relies somewhat on drivers, which do not seem to export through FBX.

However, armature animations (and even scaling/rotating/translating) do export, which coverse the second half of my animations; so it seems like it should be easy to work around. Currently I've been manually transforming every armature to match what the driver would have had it doing, and this has worked well enough, but it is fairly tedious.

Is it possible to "commit" a driver's actions in an animation and remove it, simply leaving everything moving as it would have with the driver around? If so, how does one do it?

Comment: You should be able to use Bake Action to bake the driver to a set of keyframes - you can then disable the driver.

Comment: Thanks, @RichSedman; I figured it out. You just saved me maybe a day of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out, with the help of Rich Sedman.

What I'm doing now is establishing a complete animation in Blender, with the use of drivers and empties. Blender drivers are python-dependent, so of course they don't export; but by doing the following I can make the FBX animation-ready.

1. Bake the movement of the empty. (This option is in the 3D view, under Object->Animation->Bake Action)
2. Bake the animation of the target mesh in the same way.
3. Open up the graph view, go to Drivers and then the driver pane on the right, and remove the driver. It's no longer necessary.
4. Delete the empty that was in use. I suggest this because otherwise, the animation applying to the empty will still export; and FBX doesn't do much for identifying which meshes are associated with which animations. Tools like Unreal and Unity will get confused, and most likely apply it to the end mesh.
5. Export the animation as an FBX file, and it should be ready to use.

Comment: I want to echo these instructions for Blender 3.3 (and the importance of deleting the drivers manually via the Driver Editor). My setup is "Object" with custom property "P" parented to "Armature" with "Bone". P drives the X rotation on Bone with keyframes on "Action". I can bake the animation on Armature via Object mode->Object->Animation->Bake Action (selecting Bake Data as "Pose"). If I delete the original "Action", however, the baked keyframes appear in the Dope Sheet but the model doesn't move.

Comment: There was no option for deleting the driver by right-clicking the X rotation on the Bone Properties panel in Pose mode. The X rotation on "Bone" was actually highlighted in brown/yellow (not purple). 

I needed to open the Driver Editor (Shift-F6, or select from the Animation section of the dropdown window selection panel) and delete the drivers manually. After that, the source Action could be deleted and the baked animation remains.